# Word used to describe a contradictory appearance for the intended meaning of a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I could be completely wrong, but I feel like there is a word for it.

To explain my meaning, let's use the word "Circular". This means "Round" or sometimes "Spherical". Writing it one way, to put a visual appearance of the word might be: (I just used an online font, so ignore the extra "bits")

[image: Cursive Font]

However, if I wrote it a different way:

[image: Angular Font]

The *appearance* of the word (blocky and square-ish) contradicts the *meaning* of the word.

Is there a word for this (other than just "Contradictory")?

Comment: [*Heterological*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heterological) is close, but normally refers to how a word's *definition* rather than appearance doesn't describe itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call it *paradoxical*. If you wanted a fancy $10 word, maybe [*anti-ideasthetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideasthesia).

(Also check out the [Stroop Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect).)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a $10 000 word or a bust. Since I haven't found it anywhere else, I'd say it's not a word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you can find _ideasthesia_ in Wikipedia where you can find further references. _Anti_ is a standard prefix.

Comment: 'Standard', whatever you mean by it, doesn't mean 'totally productive' and certainly not 'will always give an idiomatic new word'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, where do you think new words come from? People make them up, especially in technical contexts. They catch on or they don't. At one time there was no such word as _antimatter_. One day, someone thought, "Gee, we need a new word to call this new type of matter that we have discovered. Let's take the standard prefix _anti-_, and stick it on the front of _matter_." Would you have objected to that?

Comment: We've had the debate here several times on what constitutes 'wordness' (and that word _can_ be found in at least some dictionaries). Inclusion in OED is usually taken as being sufficient proof. 'People make [new words] up, especially in technical contexts. They catch on or they don't. ... If you wanted a fancy $10 word, maybe _anti-ideasthetic_.' isn't.